# Access model instance methods in view (Sails.js / EJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I've noticed that when a model instance (object) is passed to a view it is stripped of all functions. Is there any way around this?

Example:

My User model has method fullName which intelligently merges first name, last name, and prefix.

In the controller I have:

```
User.find().done(function(err,users){
  res.view({
    users:users
  });
});
```

If I loop through users in the controller I can do user.fullName();

If I do the same in the view I get an undefined method error.

I can access the model attributes directly in either the controller or view (eg user.firstName, user.lastName)

On other MVC architectures (eg. rails / zendPHP) I usually do things like this in the model and can call user.fullName() wherever I need it in the view which allows me to keep DRY and consistent throughout the system.

Why doesn't this work and is there a way to make it work?

**Model**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        email: {
          type: 'string',
          required: true,
          unique: true,
          email: true
        },
        password: {
          type: 'string',
          required: true
        },
        firstName: {
          type: 'string',
          required: false,
          maxLength: 50,
          minLength: 2
        },
        lastName: {
          type: 'string',
          required: false,
          maxLength: 50,
          minLength: 2
        },

        // Returns full name of user (or just first / last if that's all we have)
        getFullName: function(){
          return _.str.trim((this.firstName || '') + ' ' + (this.lastName || ''));
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
<tr>
  <td><%= user.id %></td>
  <td><%= user.email %></td>
  <td><%= user.getFullName() %></td>
  <td><%= user.status %></td>
  <td><%= user.createdAt %></td>
  <td>
    <a href="#<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-xs icon-edit"></a>
    <a href="#<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-xs icon-trash"></a>
  </td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
```

I've also tried console.log(user) in the loop and console.log(users) before the loop in both the controller and the view and it's obvious methods are stripped when the model is passed to the view. I've also tried the build in method user.toJSON() and I get an undefined method error in the view, but it works as expected in the controller.

Comment: Works for me. Could you post your model and your view code?

Comment: Plus: Which version of Sails are you using?

Comment: v0.10 ... I don't think it has anything to do with my model or view code as even the built in functions toJSON() don't work. Also, if I console.log the whole user object on the controller AND the view the getters/setters for associations are removed too.

Comment: @marionebl I added model / view code. Although, it's nothing special. I can tell via console.log that the users object is intact in the controller, but that the methods are stripped when it gets to the view.

Comment: Can't reproduce in this [test application](https://github.com/marionebl/sails-model-instance-demo). Try accessing `localhost:1337/test/test` after `sails lift`.

Comment: Odd, @marionebl, I get the same error with your test app... Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Iq2rGhq.png ...maybe it's my local version of sails. Sails -v gives me 0.10.0

Comment: Could be a version hickup - try to reinstall Sails via `npm install sails@beta`, my version is 0.10.0-rc3

Comment: @marionebl, Upgrading sails to the latest beta worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I hate resurrecting an old thread, but for what it's worth, this problem still seems to be present on associated models. In the `test` example, if `Test` has an attribute `foo` and class `Foo` had an instance method `bar`, then `test.foo.bar()` still does not seem to work.

Comment: @marionebl can I use my controller method in my view file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one have to run a `pop()` function on the array before using `toJSON`. Then you will have access to the attribute methods in the view. See how it is used in the [sails documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json). However this would of course delete the last element in the array...

Comment: I wasn't calling .toJSON on the array I was doing it on the individual instances in a forEach loop. By the way, if you just want one and you don't want to modify the array you could use users[0].toJSON()